# Why is plymouth-log-viewer starting up?

Tags: fedora, boot, logs

I've been using Fedora 14 for about a month on my primary system (converted from Win2K). My secondary system was converted to Fedora 12 from Win2K, and was updated sequentially to Fedora 14 (using package-update both times).

Recently, my primary system started showing an alert icon in the notification area immediately after login - a yellow triangle with an "!" in it. When I click on the triangle, I get a window titled "Boot Messages" with the following content:

```
        Welcome to Fedora 
Starting udev:                                             [  OK  ]
Setting hostname gravastar.oakenhammer.org:                [  OK  ]
Setting up Logical Volume Management:   3 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_gravastar" now active
                                                           [  OK  ]
Checking filesystems
_Fedora-14-i686-: clean, 161569/1638400 files, 1511990/6553600 blocks
/dev/sda1: clean, 47/128016 files, 81952/512000 blocks
/dev/mapper/vg_gravastar-lv_home: clean, 55815/1646592 files, 1597690/6578176 blocks
                                                           [  OK  ]
Remounting root filesystem in read-write mode:             [  OK  ]
Mounting local filesystems:                                [  OK  ]
Enabling /etc/fstab swaps:                                 [  OK  ]
Entering non-interactive startup
Starting monitoring for VG vg_gravastar:   3 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_gravastar" monitored
                                                           [  OK  ]
ip6tables: Applying firewall rules:                        [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
Starting portreserve:                                      [  OK  ]
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
Enabling p4-clockmod driver (passive cooling only):        [  OK  ]
Starting irqbalance:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting mdmonitor:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting system message bus:                               [  OK  ]
Setting network parameters...                              [  OK  ]
Starting NetworkManager daemon:                            [  OK  ]
Starting Avahi daemon...                                   [  OK  ]
Starting cups:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting HAL daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
Retrigger failed udev events                               [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sendmail:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting sm-client:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting abrt daemon:                                      [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting crond:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting atd:                                              [  OK  ]
Starting jexec services
```

This content corresponds exactly to the full content of `/var/log/boot.log`. Some poking around determined that this was the process `plymouth-log-viewer`, and that it is a graphical boot log viewer.

I can understand this occurring if there's a boot problem. However, reviewing the content of the log does not seem to reveal any problems. Also, it's somewhat disconcerting that my only option once the viewer appears is to right-click the "!" and select "`Quit`".

Can anyone provide any information on why this is happening, and how to stop it? This does not happen on my secondary system at all, and I cannot identify any significant discrepancies between the two systems.

The only information that appears to indicate a potential cause is the following fragments from `/var/log/messages`:

**UPDATE** The message content below also appears in the same log file on my secondary system, where `plymouth-log-viewer` is not triggered on login.

Repeats several times:

```
Dec 18 19:18:51 gravastar NetworkManager[1069]: <error> [1292717931.616234] [nm-manager.c:1332] user_proxy_init(): could not init user settings proxy: (3) Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings': no such name
```

Occurs once:

```
Dec 18 19:18:59 gravastar gdm-simple-greeter[1564]: Gtk-WARNING: gtkwidget.c:5691: widget not within a GtkWindow
Dec 18 19:19:00 gravastar gdm-simple-greeter[1564]: WARNING: Unable to load CK history: no seat-id found
Dec 18 19:19:09 gravastar gdm-simple-greeter[1564]: WARNING: Failed to send buffer
```

Occurs once:

```
Dec 18 19:19:44 gravastar dbus: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.60" (uid=500 pid=1815 comm="nautilus) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination=":1.18" (uid=0 pid=1461 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is a bug in plymouth included in Fedora 14. Was fixed in Fedora 16 as said in this bug report http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=586098. There was something wrong in the bootup, but plymouth won't show you, since it's input is truncated. The solution, upgrade to Fedora 16.